# How can I extract the first word of every line of a text file in C#

Tags: c#

Currently trying to read the first word of every line

```
while ((line = studentsReader.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    foreach (var lines in line.Split('\n'))
    {                        
        arr = line.Split(',');                      
    }
}
```

Tried that but it doesn't work, `arr[1]` still gives me the name `Oliver`

I want `arr[0]` to be `v12345` and `arr[1]` to be `v54321` not `Oliver`

The text file looks something like this:

```
v12345, Oliver, Queen
v54321, Barry, Allen
v51213, Tony, Stark
```

Comment: I believe, you don't need `foreach (var lines in line.Split('\n'))` as reader ReadLine gives you each line string value and with split method, you can get first element by arr[0]

Comment: Arrays are 0 based. Meaning the first element is on position arr[0] instead of arr[1]

Comment: In C#, arrays use zero-based indexing, so the first element in an array is index 0.  So, as @AkashKC points out, you should be looking at studentIDs[0].

Comment: Edited my question, wasnt clear

Comment: @pm100 arr[1] would give me Oliver, i need arr[1] to give me v54321

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the first word to a new collection.

```
var arr = new List<string>();
while ((line = studentsReader.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    arr.Add(line.Split(',')[0]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! And arr.Add(line.Split(',')[1]); would give the second work? Trying to understand the logic

Comment: Yes, `line.Split(',')[1]` would give you the `first name` and `line.Split(',')[2]` would give the `last name` if I am inferring the data correctly.

Answer (score 1):

if this is a file then you can do

```
var arr = File.ReadLines(<file name>).Select(l=>l.Split(',')[0]).ToList();
```

Answer (score -1):

Sorry. but your code is a mess.

```
while ((line = studentsReader.ReadLine()) != null)//ReadLine reads only one line from a file, e. g. v12345, Oliver, Queen
{
    foreach (var lines in line.Split('\n'))//spiltting than single line by '\n' does nothing
    {
        /*Now you split by ',' not the iterator, which is lines,
         but an original string, which is line.
         But because you didn't actually split anything it makes no difference*/                        
         arr = line.Split(',');
         /*here you've got an array of strings {v12345, Oliver, Queen}
         On next iteration you'll read another line from a file and
         get the same array from another string, etc. And on each iteration
         the arr will be a new array, so after the last iteration you'll get
         the last line of file*/                      
    }
}
```

You should do something like this

```
List<string> firstWords = new List<string>();

while(line = studentsReader.ReadLine()!=null)
{
    firstWords.Add(line.Split(',')[0]);

}
```

Answer (score -2):

the array index is zero based. so arr[0] will give you the first word.

Comment: Yes I am aware, but I want arr[0] to be v12345 and arr[1] to be v54321 not "Oliver"